# Using alert with a variable parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to to use `Mystring` as alert's parameter so when mouse on the link, it will alert `Mystring`?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    window.onload = initAll;

    function initAll() {
        var Mystring = "Hello world";
        var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        aTag.onmouseover = runAlert;
    }

    function runAlert() {
        alert(Mystring);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">Over me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Mystring` variable is scoped inside `initAll` function. It is not available outside that function. What you might want to do is define it outside and assign the value in `initAll`, like this:

```
window.onload = initAll;
var myString;

function runAlert() {
    alert(myString);
}

function initAll() {
    myString = "Hello world";
    var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    aTag.onmouseover = runAlert;
}
```

If this all you are going to do, you can define an in-line anonymous function, like this

```
    aTag.onmouseover = function() {
        alert(myString);
    };
```

**Note:** Normally JavaScript variables are named with camelCase convention.

**Note 1:** It is always a good practice to define the called functions before the calling functions, like I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your scopes and avoid global pollution, you can assign a parameter to your alert function:

```
function initAll() {
    var Mystring = "Hello world";
    var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    aTag.onmouseover = function(){runAlert(Mystring)};
}

function runAlert(str) {
    alert(str);
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ69x/

Comment: on line4, what is the different between aTag.onmouseover = function(){runAlert(Mystring)}; and  aTag.onmouseover = runAlert(Mystring);? thanks

Comment: That would run the `runAlert` function on init and assign its result to the onmouseover method. It won't work as you expected it, as you'd get the alert when the page loads. This way, onmouseover is a function that calls another function.

Comment: why onmouseover won't work if i call the function by just its name.
aTag.onmouseover = runAlert(Mystring);   ?

Comment: Because your runAlert function is used for displaying the alert and it doesn't return anything (it returns undefined). So, `aTag.onmouseover = runAlert(Mystring);` would be the same as `aTag.onmouseover = undefined;` and onmouseover should be a function. See this simple example I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/LL3Hq/